# .Net Core Azure AD authentication failes since Hybrid Active Directory

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .Net Core 5 MVC application that uses Azure AD and 2FA for authentication. This has worked perfectly for a long time.

But now we switched to [Hybrid Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-managed-domains) and now login is no longer possible in Edge or Chrome.

I changed nothing to my own code.
In Startup.cs

```
 services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

in appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "ClientId": "***",
  "TenantId": "***",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "ClientSecret": "***",
  "Domain": "***.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

The nuget identity packages used are Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.web.UI

When using Firefox everything works like before. I can login with 2FA and everything works fine. But Chrome and Edge give me the problems. An authentication request is sent and it seems to be successfull. When the sysadmin checks in the Azure Portal all authentication requests are marked "Success" but in my application i'm not logged in. I stay on de login page

When i try a direct page url, the browser tries to log me in multiple times but it ends with the message that i cannot be logged in and to try again later.

Do i have to make adjustments to my project to work with hybride Azure Active Directory?
Not sure if more information is needed to make my question more clear

EDIT: i made some progress but no solution. It seems to involve the Mads Kristensen Service Worker nuget package ([LINK](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker)). If i remove this package, everything works fine. If active, i have to remove a cookie to get authentication. The next time i open the application, no more authentication until i remove the cookie. It could be a total coincidence and not related

EDIT 2 : I found [THIS](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker/issues/88) on the github issues page. I think the issues might be related

Answer (score 0):

To work with hybrid Azure Active Directory, there are some review things ,certain considerations and unsupported  scenarios that  you should know and also the right authentication method for your Azure Active Directory hybrid identity solution.
please refer the following links for more information.
[Plan your hybrid Azure Active Directory join implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-plan) ,
[Choose the right authentication method for your Azure Active Directory hybrid identity solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/choose-ad-authn)

Comment: I edited my original question. It might have something to do with Mads Kristensen PWA package: [link]https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker/issues/88